# ArgumentNullException was unhandled - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: first

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace, argumentnullexception

I am currently using the DotSpatial library for .NET (GIS Library). I am getting an error within my AppManager class. The AppManager is a Component that manages the loading of extensions (including data providers), and helps with file serialization:

**Code being flagged at foreach**

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDirectoriesNestedOneLevel()
{
       // Visit each directory in Directories Property (usually set by application)
    foreach (string directory in Directories.Union(new[] { "Data Extensions", "Tools" }))
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, directory);

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            yield return path;

            // Add all of the directories in here, nested one level deep.
            var dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                yield return dir;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ParamName**

> first

**Source**

> System.Core

**StackTrace**

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Union[TSource](IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second)    at
>   DotSpatial.Controls.AppManager.d__9.MoveNext()
>   in c:\dev\DotSpatial\DotSpatial.Controls\Extensions\AppManager.cs:line
>   581    at DotSpatial.Controls.AppManager.GetCatalog() in
>   c:\dev\DotSpatial\DotSpatial.Controls\Extensions\AppManager.cs:line
>   563    at DotSpatial.Controls.AppManager.LoadExtensions() in
>   c:\dev\DotSpatial\DotSpatial.Controls\Extensions\AppManager.cs:line
>   329    at DemoMap.MainForm..ctor() in C:\Users\Logan B.
>   Lehman\Documents\DemoMap\DemoMap\MainForm.cs:line 230    at
>   DemoMap.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Logan B.
>   Lehman\Documents\DemoMap\DemoMap\Program.cs:line 13    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

**Any idea on what is going on here?** **It would be more than appreciated**

Comment: first foreach or second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that 'Directories' is null.  It's not clear from the code snippet where that *should* be set, but in this case it is not being set.  The error is a little cryptic because of the way Union is implemented: it is an extension method, so behind the scenes the actual call is:

```
IEnumerableExtensions.Union(IEnumerable first, IEnumerable second)
```

Depending on what Directories is, one quick fix would be, before the foreach:

```
if (Directories == null) { Directories = new List<string>().ToArray(); }
```

Another possibility would be something like:

```
var allDirs = new List<string>();
if (Directories != null) { allDirs.AddRange(Directories);}
allDirs.AddRange(new[]{ "Data Extensions", "Tools" });
foreach(string directory in allDirs)
```

But a better fix would be to go to the code that sets directories and make sure it's always setting a value...

Comment: Daniel, Thanks a lot for this. When I go to set the directories (which is in the DotSpatial.Controls.AppManager properties), it returns an error, "Constructor on type 'System.String' not found."

So unfortunately at this time, it cannot have a value because of this. If I could fix that error, then this should not be a problem.

Comment: Just to be sure to gracefully handle a null 'Directories' somehow.  I edited the reply to include another possible fix.

Answer (score 0):

The `Directories` property is null, find out why this is.

Answer (score 0):

write this with one more line of code where you compute the list of directories to make code more clear, pleaaaase !
Are you sure you are using union properly ? like AUnionB= A.Union(B) ?? Not clear in your code.